# How to align left or revert back the default bootstrap navbar alignment in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 for my navigation and in media query 991px the navigation is set to align center. here's my css:

```
.navbar-nav {
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float:none;
}
```

but the problem is when it reach to media query 768px the navbar it stills sit's in the center. What I want to happen is when it reach to 768 the navbar alignment return to left(default alignment) and the navigation will collapse every time I click the burger menu.

Comment: can you please your code with media query

Comment: this what I did:   .navbar-nav {
      float:left;
      margin:0 ;
      display: unset;
      text-align: unset;
  }

  .navbar-nav > li {
      display: unset;
      float:left;
  }

but no luck still won't revert back the default navbar in mobile view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to align the nav bar to center between `768px` and `991px`, then you should set your media query as follow :

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 768px ) and (max-width: 991px) {
        .navbar-nav {
          float:none;
          margin:0 auto;
          display: block;
          text-align: center;
       }

    .navbar-nav > li {
         display: inline-block;
         float:none;
      }
   }
```

Comment: you nailed it! This media query css work's perfectly! Thank you :)

Comment: Cheers !! Glad it helped :)

Comment: I have a question. how to stop this jquery when it reach to 768 here's the code: jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
 }, function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
 });

. I tried using var width = jQuery(window).width(); and var width = jQuery(document).width(); but no luck.

Comment: @MelvinRey i think `.unbind()` function can do the trick ...`if($(window).width() < 768) {   $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
 } `... but i'm not entirely sure .. you sould add it as a question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try your code like this. it will only work with width of 991 and above

```
 @media all and (min-width: 991px){

.navbar-nav {
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float:none;
} }
```